# get temperature of motherboard and cpu and other hardware stats

Tags: cpu, motherboard

My motherboard, an asus p5n-e sli, came with an assetup.exe driver which when installed provided me with stats of my motherboard and cpu hardware. It included temperature, among other things. Unfortunately, that only works on windows xp and windows vista. I now use windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04, and I can't seem to find a windows 7/ubuntu compatible cd. When i try to install the one that came with the motherboard, I just get an error like "operating system not supported".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your bios by pressing the DEL button when your computer starts up. Or whatever key your motherboard prompts you to press to get into the bios.

According to [this](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5NE_SLI/specifications/) it says you're using award bios. I'm not sure what version, but you should look for a section about PC power or health status, and it will give you, your temperature readings.

[image]

Now if you're looking for a solution while in windows, i'd recommend using [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) or [Realtemp](http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/)

[image]

Comment: ok and I assume the ubuntu equivalent would be http://www.lm-sensors.org/